# Open Terminal Shows : bash: alias: =: not found How to remove?

Tags: command-line, bash, 16.04

when i open my terminal it shows:

```
bash: alias: osmall: not found
bash: alias: =: not found
bash: alias: cd: not found
bash: alias: /var/www/html/OpenSupermall/: not found
bash: alias: /var/www/html/OpenSupermall/: not found
alias osmall='cd'
bash: alias: /var/www/html/OpenSupermall/: not found
bash: alias: /var/www/html/OpenSupermall/: not found
```

It's so annoying to me. How can I get rid of this message ?
Thanks

Comment: Probably you have outdated stuff in your `~/.bashrc` and/or `~/.bash_aliases` file. Remove the incorrect lines. (Or show those files here by editing your question.)

Comment: Hey man !! u saved my life.. !! i didnt know about .bash_aliases file.. I opened up and yes found some outdated aliases .. i removed them and yes now it all ok.. Bro can u tell me or suggest me "How to create permanent aliases" ??

thanks

Comment: Use the very same file: `alias somecommand='command to run'`

Comment: My errors did not go away until I deleted the .bash_aliases file. Simply clearing the file did not work for me. Must have been some meta file or something.